# How can integrate UHF C72 RFID Reader into Flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sdk, rfid

How can I integrate UHF C72 RFID reader to flutter application for communicating with server?

I have a flutter application to communicate the RFID tag with server, and the tag will be scanned through this C72 reader.

I have checked with flutter plugin 'uhf_c72_plugin_2 0.2.8' but didn't find a proper documentation for connecting this with reader.

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin, and you can refer to documents here with an example.

https://pub.dev/packages/uhf_c72_plugin

To connect server and APIs try "axios"

https://pub.dev/packages/axios

Answer (score 0):

First you should check out the web site of UHF C72 RFID. There must be an sdk file and sample codes. Usually there is one java option. If you want to use flutter, create your flutter app with java source code then implement your java sdk in your android source files. You need to  code channel interfaces both flutter and java sides(Sender and Receiver). Look for the channel interfaces for java-flutter.